# How to send automatic messages to the user through whatsapp without confirmation

Tags: whatsapp

I have the following link on my website https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxxx&text=hello. When clicking on the link, a message is inserted in the text field of the user's cell phone for him to confirm and only then is the message sent to the indicated number. Is it possible to send an automatic message through the Whatsapp API without having the user's number and without prior confirmation?

I consulted the Whatsapp API and all routes need to indicate the recipient's number and as the user just clicked on the link I don't have his number and if he doesn't confirm the conversation doesn't start